# fileUpload not working in primefaces wizard

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

In p:wizard i have a file upload in first tab.When,I move to next tab uploaded image get empty.How to solve this problem to set a image in first tab.Please,any one help me..........

```
<p:wizard>
    <p:tab id="tabbranch" title="Branch" titleStyle="font-size:14px;">  
        <p:panel id="display" >
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Branch File" 
                    style="text-align: left;display: block;width:120px"/>
                <p:fileUpload value="#{branchBean.current.buildingPlan}" 
                    allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" mode="simple" style="width:185px"/>     
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="Profile page 1" titleStyle="font-size:14px;">
        <p:panel>                   
            <h:outputLabel value="Name:*" style="text-align: left;display: block;width:130px;"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{branchBean.current.branchName}"
                readonly="#{searchBean.selectedCustomer.editAccess}"
                style="width:170px;" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

Comment: Which primefaces and JSF versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using primefaces showcase and version primefaces-3.5

Comment: Where is your listener method? Please refer to the [showcase use](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf)

Comment: I have a file upload in first tab and after selecting any image if I click next tab, the selected image is gone/refreshed. So I don't get the value for fileupload in my managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

From PrimeFaces User Guide 3.5 (http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf):

1) Add the following libs to your project: commons-fileupload 1.2.1 and commons-io 1.4;

2) Map the following filters in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
       org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
   </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Not explained in Primefaces User Guide:

1) Configure your h:form as multipart/form-data

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```